# Special characters when sending email with python

Tags: python

I am sending email with python as follows:

```
if myresult > 0:
   remetente    = 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
   senha        = 'xxxxx'

   destinatario = ['xxxxx@xxxxxxx.xx']
   assunto      = 'Encomendas'
   texto        = 'Existem Encomendas na plataforma aguardar decisão.'

   msg = '\r\n'.join([
      'From: %s' % remetente,
      'To: %s' % destinatario,
      'Subject: %s' % assunto,
      '',
      '%s' % texto
   ])

   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
   server.starttls()
   server.login(remetente,senha)
   server.sendmail(remetente, destinatario, msg)
   server.quit()
```

The email is sent without problem, but the user receives the email with errors because of this caratere `~` in this word **"decisão"**.

As it is in the email to the user: **decisÃ£o**
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman version 2.7.12

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

> texto = texto.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(texto,unicode)  else texto

Comment: Did not work, continue with the same result

Comment: The text is already encoded as UTF-8, it's just that there is no header to tell the client which encoding ("charset") to use.